# Understanding Maven Version Ranges

Tags: java, maven

Assume that I have an artifact with versions

```
1.0-SNAPSHOT, 1.0, 1.1, 1.2-SNAPSHOT
```

in my Maven repository. Now, when I specify a version range

```
[1.0-SNAPSHOT,)
```

for this artifact (and assume there are no other version requirements), will Maven resolve it to 1.1 or 1.2-SNAPSHOT?

I have read that version ranges resolve to release versions if both boundaries are release versions but haven't understood the exact behaviour if one of the boundaries is a SNAPSHOT.

Background: For some legacy reasons, we have release artifacts which depend on SNAPSHOT artifacts. These SNAPSHOT artifacts are removed when a release version is available (which breaks Maven builds). Logically, I am aiming for the behaviour: Take the SNAPSHOT version, but replace it with a release version as soon as one is available.

Comment: Really release artifacts which depend on SNAPSHOT? You have lost your reproducibility. Furthermore I recommend to prevent using version ranges.

Comment: @khmarbaise Let me explain: We are just starting a transition from Ant to Maven. In Ant, people used SNAPSHOT and RC dependencies in their release versions. These artifacts have to be imported into our Nexus, together with generated POMs. Therefore, we need to support releases that depend on SNAPSHOTs. Naturally, these SNAPSHOTs should be deleted when a release version is available. My best idea to handle this situation are version ranges.

Answer (score 2):

I just tested, maven resolved it to 1.2-SNAPSHOT

So the priority seems to be:

1. Look for the latest version (1.2)
2. Take Release if available. Else SNAPSHOT

Comment: Thank you for the test: This means that Maven just takes the largest version, no matter if it is SNAPSHOT or not.